# Binomial rule and repeatedly differentiating

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, binomial-theorem

Exercise from book:

Show that for all positive integers n
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) k^{j}= \begin{cases}0, & j=0,1, \ldots, n-1 \\
(-1)^{n} n ! j=n\end{cases}
$$

and hint from author:

Hint. Expand $(1-x)^{n}$ by the binomial rule. Repeatedly differentiate, but with a twist.

My question: what does mean differentiate with a twist??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Expanding $(1-x)^n$ and differentiating $j$ times we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^j}{dx^j}\left((1-x)^n\right)&=\frac{d^j}{dx^j}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^k\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\color{blue}{k(k-1)\cdots(k-j+1)}x^{k-j}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
This is near to what we want, but instead of $k(k-1)\cdots(k-j+1)=\frac{k!}{(k-j)!}$ we need $k^j$. We observe that differentiating $e^{kx}$ $j$ times results in
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^j}{dx^j}\left(e^{kx}\right)=\color{blue}{k^j}e^{kx}
\end{align*}
So, we can add a twist to (1) by differentiating
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\left(1-e^{kx}\right)^n}
\end{align*}
$j$ times instead of $(1-x)^n$ and then evaluating at $x=0$.