# Prove that the $n$th difference of $x^n$ is $\sum _{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}(x-i)^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, induction

> Prove that the $n$th difference of $x^n$ is $\displaystyle \sum \limits _{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}(x-i)^n$ (here the first difference is $\Delta (x^n):=(x)^n-(x-1)^n$ and the $n$th difference is defined recursively as $\Delta ^n(x^n):=\Delta ^{n-1}((x)^n)-\Delta ^{n-1}((x-1)^n)$).

I tried using induction, but just proving $\Delta ^n(x^n)$ is given by the indicated formula for all $n$ doesn't seem to work. Instead, I may need a more general formula involving $\Delta ^n(x^m)$, where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers. However, I'm not sure how to come up with this more general formula.

Comment: The pattern is not hard to establish, do $\Delta (x^n), \Delta^2(x^n),...$.

Comment: @Gord452 FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5En(-1)%5Ei%7Bn%5Cchoose%20i%7D(x-i)%5En%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Adifference&p=4), I found the AoPS thread [nth Difference Sequence of nth Powers](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1983800p13797464) (in particular, message #$4$), plus quite a few closely related questions on this site, especially [$k$th difference of $1,2^k,3^k,...$](/q/697558/602049). There are many other associated questions, e.g., proving the expression is $n!$, eg., such as at the AoPS thread ...

Comment: I imagine it should be $(x+i)^n$ above? And $(-1)^i$ should be $(-1)^{n-i}$, I believe.

Comment: @Gord452 (cont.) [An interesting identity](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1733727p11247892), and on this site there's [Binomial Sum: Values](/q/1340837), [Why does this process generate the factorial of the exponent?](/q/2078853), [Repeatedly taking differences on a polynomial yields the factorial of its degree?](/q/2319210), [Expressing a factorial as difference of powers: $\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}(-1)^r(l-r)^n=n!$?](/q/591350), [Combinatorial proof of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}(l-k)^n=n!$, using inclusion-exclusion](/q/1862571), etc.

Comment: it remands me https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298639/binomial-rule-and-repeatedly-differentiating this question I think differentiating repeatedly  (x-i)^n will help

Comment: It is much more natural to define $\Delta^n$ as $\Delta\circ \Delta^{n-1}$. $(\Delta p)(x)=p(x+1)-p(x), (\Delta^2 p)(x)=p(x+2)-2p(x+1)+p(x), (\Delta^3 p)(x) = p(x+3)-3 p(x+2)+3 p(x+1)-p(x)$ and in general $$(\Delta^n p)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k p(x+n-k)$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio for reference this was question B5 of the 1976 putnam exam. An answer I got says the result is $n!$ because it's the nth difference of $x^n$. Is the logic behind that wrong then?

Comment: I am not quite getting the point of the formula, the $n$th difference is $n!$, so why are you focused on the above formula?

Answer (score 2):

This problem refers to the *[backward difference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BackwardDifference.html)* operator
\begin{align*}
\Delta\left(x^n\right):= x^n-(x-1)^{n}
\end{align*}
We can prove the formula
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\Delta^n\left(x^n\right)=\sum _{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}(x-i)^n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
using operator methods. We introduce the shift operator $E$ and identity operator $I$ with
\begin{align*}
Ef(x)&=f(x+1)\\
If(x)&=f(x)
\end{align*}
We can write the delta operator $\Delta$ as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\Delta}\left(x^n\right)&=x^n-\left(x-1\right)^n\\
&=I\left(x^n\right)-E^{-1}\left(x^n\right)\\
&=\color{blue}{\left(I-E^{-1}\right)}\left(x^n\right)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Since shift operator $E$ and identity operator $I$ are linear operators which commute we obtain according to (2) using the binomial theorem

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\Delta^n\left(x^n\right)}&=\left(I-E^{-1}\right)^n\left(x^n\right)\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(-1)^iE^{-i}I^{n-i}\left(x^n\right)\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(-1)^iE^{-i}\left(x^n\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(-1)^i\left(x-i\right)^n}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

Answer (score 0):

Define $(Rf)(x) = f(x)-f(x-1)$. Note that $R$ is linear. It is straightforward using induction to show that
$(R^nf )(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k f(x-k)$.

Abusing notation slightly, we see that for any constant $c$ we have $Rc = 0$ and that $Rx^p$ is a polynomial of degree $p-1$ with coefficient $p = \binom{p}{1}$. In particular,
$R^n x^n = n!$ and so
$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k (x-k)^n = n!$.